# solving for a large number of unknowns by substitution or simulation

Tags: substitution, simulation

I am trying to develop a streamline method to solve for the variables in equations of the sort:

$E+F+G=25$

$E+H+I=40$

$F+H+J=35$

$G+I+J=30$

The equations I need to solve will have up to $20$ variables. An online tool would be useful.

Thanks

Comment: You may want to try using matrices.

Comment: I googled for "online linear equation solver" and found [this](http://wims.unice.fr/wims/en_tool~linear~linsolver.en.html).